# How to read image one after the other before upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html:

```
<!--multiple is set to allow multiple files to be selected-->
<input type="file" name="file"  class='uf' multiple />
```

I want to read the multiple files with JavaScript - **new FileReader()** API:

I have edited my question with answer:

```
// setup reader function
    function readmultiplefile(files, i) {
    var file    = files[i];
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
                loaded(e, files, i);
            };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function loaded(e, files, i) {

    // get file content  
     var dataurl = e.target.result;
    //html content function //custom HTML content
    var content         = "<div class='readcontent'><span class='rf' title='Remove'><button type='button'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button></span><img src='"+ dataurl +"' class='uimage' /></div>";


    //grab the element and append content
    var readfile = $("#readfile");
    readfile.append(content);

    // Continue to read  file if multiple
    if (i < files.length - 1) {
     // Load the next file
    readmultiplefile(files, i+1);
    }
    }



    //Call readmultiplefile function on a change state of input file
    $(document).on('change','.uf',function(){
        //read file
        readmultiplefile(this.files, 0);

    });
```

The above code works fine  because I have edited the question and replace the answer for other to use.

Thank you

Comment: There's an extra closing tag, don't know if that's because there's a matching opening one that's not included in your code or what

Comment: your `reader.readAsDataURL` is not in the loop

Comment: okay now I've put that inside the loop and the htmlcontent function appends the number of files selected but only last one file is read. Any idea please?

Comment: I think the reader.readAsDataURL does not finish reading the fille then it loops again